# Check if link to jsFiddle is actually a link to code

Tags: feature-request, jsfiddle

I get why there is a check to avoid links to jsFiddle without code. I agree with the check. But recently I wanted to quote a user on [the github page for jsFiddle](https://github.com/jsfiddle/jsfiddle-issues/issues/311), which included a link to `http://jsfiddle.net/draft`. This isn't a link to a jsfiddle piece of code, it's just a link to the homepage.

I fixed it now by adding a space after the h in http, which seems kind of dorky. All I want to do, is to quote the user correctly. You can see [the question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260947/why-jsfiddle-is-not-rendering-at-all-in-ie8-and-older-versions/15268966#15268966).

So I would propose allowing links to jsfiddle pages that have no code in them (not sure how many there are though).

Just throwing an idea out, I'm interested in what opinions there are.

Comment: Actually checking the target of the link seems a bit much, but the jsfiddle link check does seem entirely too abrasive. It won't even accept the link in backticks. I hacked around it in a slightly less visually intrusive way.

Comment: "Nice" fix @TimStone

Comment: Better fix for the reader indeed.

Comment: @Bart Ain't nobody got time for that unforgiving regex shenaniganery. ;)

Comment: This question might be related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159258/dont-just-link-to-jsfiddle-net-hint-sometimes-hinders-answering-the-questions.